# Fill subsequent values of python pandas dataframe with zeros when a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When a value in "Returns" column is less than "m"(say m=-0.5), I want the subsequent rows to be filled with zeros only till that month end. How to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(365), freq='D')
np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': days, 'Price': data})
df = df.set_index('test')
df['Returns']=df['Price'].pct_change()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with mask for compare `Returns` for less like `m` and aggregate [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) with `shift` for `< m` per months by [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
np.random.seed(123)
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(365), freq='D')
np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': days, 'Price': data})
df = df.set_index('test')
df['Returns']=df['Price'].pct_change()
    
    
m = -0.5

m = (df['Returns'].lt(m)
                  .groupby(df.index.to_period('m'))
                  .transform(lambda x: x.shift().cummax())
                  .fillna(False))
```

---

```
df['Returns'] = np.where(m, 0, df['Returns'])
print (df)
                            Price   Returns
test                                       
2021-11-22 14:32:35.550767     29       NaN
2021-11-23 14:32:35.550767     56  0.931034
2021-11-24 14:32:35.550767     82  0.464286
2021-11-25 14:32:35.550767     13 -0.841463
2021-11-26 14:32:35.550767     35  0.000000
                          ...       ...
2022-11-18 14:32:35.550767     47  0.000000
2022-11-19 14:32:35.550767     90  0.000000
2022-11-20 14:32:35.550767     20  0.000000
2022-11-21 14:32:35.550767     27  0.000000
2022-11-22 14:32:35.550767     51  0.000000

[366 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: This replaces even the row with <-m with zero. I want next row on wards to be zeros,

Comment: On stackoverflow, first there's God and then jozefeg!

Comment: @MacroPanda - added `.fillna(False)` for avoid `NaN`s to `0`